# Rails 3: Get Count of Models via Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

In Ruby on Rails (3) with PostgreSQL and given the following three hierarchical models:

```
class Category
    has_many :posts
end

class Post
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments
end

class Comment
    belongs_to :post
end
```

Is there a way to get the total `comment` count for each `category` without having to iterate over each of the `posts`?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I would consider `has_many through` relationship.

Comment: @Jeff Completely agree, unfortunately this is an inherited project and I'm stuck with the data structure for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. All you need to do is group the relation by the column you want:

```
counts_hash = 
  Comment.
  joins(post: :category).
  group("#{Category.table_name}.id").
  count
```

That should return a hash with structure `category_id => comments_count`

However, that will exclude any categories that have 0 comments since inner-joins will be performed.

If you want to include all category IDs, for whatever reason, you'd have to include a few extra steps:

```
counts_hash.tap do |hash|
  Category.pluck(:id).each do |category_id|
    hash[category_id] = 0
  end
end
```

Alternatively:

```
# the following will return 0 as the value of any missing key
Hash.new(0).merge(counts_hash)hash
```

Comment: Awesome... Thank you! As a follow up, is there a version of this query that can be used to get the `comment` count for a specific `category`?

Comment: If you want to just get the count, you can obviously do `result_hash[your_category.id]`. If you want to restrict the query, you will need to add a condition e.g. `.where(Category.table_name => {id: your_category.id})`